# How to handle dynamodb WCU limitation ? is it queued when you go above the limit?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I need to feed the db with something like 10k items, I don't need to rush and can/want stay below the 25wcu free plan.
It will take something like 6.5minutes (10000requests/25requests/sec).

**Here is the question.** I will loop on a json to feed the base do I have to handle the number of request by second myself or can I push to the max and it will be queued ?

I read that I may just have an error message (400?) when I exceed the limit can I just brutally retry the failed requests (eventually making more fail) until my 10k items are put in the db ?

**tldr; => best way/strategy to feed the base knowing there is a limit of calls/sec**

ps: it's run from a lambda idk if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is a little bit off unless you do this constantly, because AWS actually allows you to burst a little bit ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html)):

> DynamoDB provides some flexibility in your per-partition throughput
> provisioning by providing burst capacity. Whenever you're not fully
> using a partition's throughput, DynamoDB reserves a portion of that
> unused capacity for later bursts of throughput to handle usage spikes.
>
> **DynamoDB currently retains up to 5 minutes (300 seconds) of unused**
> **read and write capacity.** During an occasional burst of read or write
> activity, these extra capacity units can be consumed quickly—even
> faster than the per-second provisioned throughput capacity that you've
> defined for your table.

Since `300 (seconds) * 25 (WCU) = 7500` this leaves you with about 7.5k items until it will actually throttle.

Afterwards just responding to the `ProvisionedThroughputExceeded` error by retrying later is fine - but make sure to **add a small delay between retries** (e.g. 1 second) as you know that it takes time for the new WCU to flow into the tocken bucket. Immediately retrying and hammering the API is not a kind way to use the service and might look like a DoS attack.

You can also write the items in [Batches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) to reduce the amount of network requests as network throughput is also limited in Lambda. This makes handling the `ProvisionedThroughputExceeded` error slightly more cumbersome, because you need to inspect the response which items failed to write, but will probably be a net positive.

Comment: This is pretty much correct -- just wanted to stress the "retrying later" part. Basically, don't just _brutally_ retry as the question implies. That will be very inefficient, causing a lot of excessive failed requests. If a request gets throttled, make sure to wait ~1 second before retrying.

Comment: @MikeDinescu you're absolutely right, I've updated the answer to emphasize that.

Comment: would it be a good solution to use batchWrite only ? batchWrite is 25items so if I launch one each second I'm 100% ok with my 25WCU limitation right ? the only thing is that I won't use the burst capacity but isn't it the best solution ?

Comment: In practice the SDK will handle retries with exponential backoff for you by default, see [batch writer](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.batch_writer) for the Python SDK, so you can just use the abstraction to write to the table. Assuming your item size is below 1KB your calculation is correct under the condition that no other entities write to the table during the import.